# Java Canvas is not visible

Tags: java, swing, canvas, javafx, awt

in my JavaApplication I have a JLayeredPane in my JFrame. The JLayeredPane contains a Canvas as a lower panel where I display a Video with a videoplayer framework. On an upper level the JLayeredPane contains an JFXPanel where I display a JavaFX.WebView. The Webview is complete transparent.

The problem is that the Canvas is only visible where the WebView is not diplayed and I see the background from the JFrame where the WebView is placed. If I disable the JFXPanel I can see the whole Canvas with the video.

I also tried to add a JPanel as the lower Level. The result was like I want to be the Canvas. I can see the complete JPanel and on top of it, it displays the WebView.

So, what can I do to make the Canvas be strong enough to display all-over the Frame. I think canvas.setOpaque would fix the problem but this Method is not available.

UPDATE:

```
    //BROWSER
    this.jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    this.jfxPanel.setOpaque(false);
    this.jfxPanel.setBounds(0,0,MainFrame.VIDEO_SIZE_X,MainFrame.VIDEO_SIZE_Y);

    PlatformImpl.startup(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            webView = new WebView();
            webView.setPrefSize(MainFrame.VIDEO_SIZE_X-100,MainFrame.VIDEO_SIZE_Y-100);
            webEngine = webView.getEngine();
            webView.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)");

            Scene scene = new Scene(webView,MainFrame.VIDEO_SIZE_X-100,MainFrame.VIDEO_SIZE_Y-100);
            scene.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.TRANSPARENT);

            webEngine.documentProperty().addListener(new DocListener());

            webEngine.loadContent("<body style='background : rgba(0,0,0,0);font-size: 70px;text-align:center;'>Test Transparent</body>");

            jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
        }
    });
    //add browser in upper level to JLayeredPane  
    this.videoPanel.add(jfxPanel, new Integer(100));
    
    //CANVAS
    this.videoCanvas = new Canvas();
    this.videoCanvas.setVisible(true);
    this.videoCanvas.setBounds(0,0, MainFrame.VIDEO_SIZE_X,MainFrame.VIDEO_SIZE_Y);
    //add canvas at lower level to JLayeredPane
    this.videoPanel.add(this.videoCanvas, new Integer(0));
```

The `videoPanel` is the JLayeredPane. It is setVisible(true) and has the same size like canvas and the browser.

Comment: please show some code..

Comment: You're mixing AWT, Swing, and JavaFX components.  No good can come from this mixture.

Comment: I have added some Code about! @GilbertLeBlanc I have to use Awt for the Player. JavaFX for the browser and the other elements are for the GUI..

Answer (score 1):

As was already mentioned by [Gilbert Le Blanc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/300257/gilbert-le-blanc), mixing AWT, Swing, and JavaFX components might complicate your project unnecessarily (see [mixing awt and swing in GUI programming using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918424/mixing-awt-and-swing-in-gui-programming-using-java) and [JavaFX Tip 9: Do Not Mix Swing / JavaFX](https://dlemmermann.wordpress.com/2014/07/17/javafx-tip-9-do-not-mix-swing-javafx/)). If you could find a Swing based web viewer and video player, it would make it easier to make it work.

You can for example look at [The DJ Project](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html) for both the web viewer and the video player (see also [Best Java/Swing browser component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145863/best-java-swing-browser-component)). The [Java Media Framework (JMF)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-jsp-140239.html), [xuggle](http://www.xuggle.com/), and the [VLC Java bindings](https://wiki.videolan.org/Java_bindings) are other options for the video player (see also [A simple way of embedding a video in my Swing GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525493/a-simple-way-of-embedding-a-video-in-my-swing-gui)).